# Entering France before long sejour visa

Tags: france, schengen-visas, long-stay-visas

I would like to travel to France before the starting date of my long sejour visa (type D). I am Canadian, so I am usually able to visit France without a explicit tourist visa. Can I enter France as a tourist prior to the start of my work visa in order to make accommodation arrangements?

I realize that I might need to exit the Schengen area and re-enter after then start date of my long sejour visa.

I've tried contacting the consulate but they haven't been answering me at all.

Comment: You should certainly be able to do this by leaving and re-entering Schengen, but I do not know whether you can do it without leaving and re-entering Schengen.

Comment: How did your entry go? Did the border guards give you any trouble? I'm planning to do the same for my trip to Austria (enter visa-free before validity of my visa-D).

Comment: When I went through border control, the agent briefly looked at my passport and didn't say anything about my French visa. I am uncertain whether he even saw that I had a visa. He then let me through. I did not exit and re-enter Schengen afterwards. I went to the police station to continue to steps to obtain my "carte de séjour" and they also weren't concerned that I had entered the country prior to the validity of my visa.